# Custom Server-rendered Gutenberg block does not always render

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have written a plugin that provides a custom "Server Side Block" that uses a callback defined in PHP that is supposed to render some HTML.

The right markup renders in certain case, but in others I just get the comment `<!-- wp:nai/serverside /-->`.

It happens mainly when I put other blocks in the page, or I put my custom block inside another.

What is wrong? Why can't I put the block wherever I want without breaking it?

Here is the code:

`plugin.php`:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @package MyPlugin
 */
/*
Plugin Name: My Plugin
Version: 1.7.2
*/

function gutenberg_examples_01_register_block() {
 
    // automatically load dependencies and version
    $asset_file = include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.asset.php');
 
    wp_register_script(
        'serverside',
        plugins_url( 'build/index.js', __FILE__ ),
        $asset_file['dependencies'],
        $asset_file['version']
    );

    wp_register_style(
        'herverside',
        plugins_url( 'style.css', __FILE__ ),
        array( ),
        filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'style.css' )
    );

 
    register_block_type('nai/serverside', array(
            'editor_script' => 'serverside',
            'render_callback' => 'render_callback',
            'attributes' => array(
                'images' => array(
                    'type' => 'array'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    function render_callback( $attributes ){
        //$images = $attributes[ 'images' ];
        return '<div>Test</div>';
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'gutenberg_examples_01_register_block' );
```

`src/index.tsx`:

```
declare var wp;

const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const el = wp.element.createElement;

const blockStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#900',
    color: '#fff',
    padding: '20px',
};

registerBlockType( 'nai/serverside', {
    title: __( 'Server Side Block', 'text-domain' ),
    icon: 'networking',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        images : {
            default: [],
            type:   'array',

        }
    },
    edit({attributes, setAttributes, className, focus, id}) {
        return (
            <div style={ blockStyle }>
                Not visible in editor mode.
            </div>
        );
    },
    save({attributes, className}) {
        /*return (
            <div style={ blockStyle }>
                Hello World, step 1 (from the frontend).
            </div>
        );*/
        return null;
    },
} );
```

Comment: You can use the [`<ServerSideRender/>`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/server-side-render) component to render the output in your `edit` function.